# Sudden SSL certificate failure with PHP/curl

Tags: php, xml, curl, ssl

Out of the blue, a single XML curl call in a php script stopped working complaining of a certificate problem:

```
SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

curl getInfo in php returns:

```
array (
    'url' => 'https://xmlpi-ea.dhl.com/XMLShippingServlet',
    'content_type' => NULL,
    'http_code' => 0,
    'header_size' => 0,
    'request_size' => 0,
    'filetime' => -1,
    'ssl_verify_result' => 0,
    'redirect_count' => 0,
    'total_time' => 0,
    'namelookup_time' => 0.034813,
    'connect_time' => 0.16098,
    'pretransfer_time' => 0,
    'size_upload' => 0,
    'size_download' => 0,
    'speed_download' => 0,
    'speed_upload' => 0,
    'download_content_length' => -1,
    'upload_content_length' => -1,
    'starttransfer_time' => 0,
    'redirect_time' => 0,
    'certinfo' => 
    array (
    )
)
```

The query is run along side one soap query (to FedEx) and two other xml queries (to UPS and USPS). The UPS query also uses a https link and is not having this problem. I have pulled and confirmed the PEM file from DHL, we have added it to the server's ca-certificates.crt file using the ubuntu recommended method, verified it was appended to the end of that file.

I have tried setting CAPATH in the code to point to the proper directory:

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAPATH, '/etc/ssl/certs/');

The only way I can get the exchange to work is to set verify off which is something we prefer not to do. (if security is available, I prefer to use it) As stated, this was working fine until a few days ago. To our knowledge, nothing on the server has changed and DHL claims nothing on their end related to ssl/certificates had changed either, and the UPS, which also uses https also works just fine with no added certificates or no other special handling.

Another oddity, the DHL still works fine on all of our development machines (albeit, they are using slightly newer versions of curl, openssl, etc.)  Are there any known problems with any versions of curl or openssl or does anyone have any other suggestions to try?

The versions on our server are as follows:

```
  libcurl3 7.19.7-1ubuntu1.5
  libcurl3-gnutls 7.19.7-1ubuntu1.5
  php5-curl 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.22
  libssl-dev 0.9.8k-7ubuntu8.15
  libssl0.9.8 0.9.8k-7ubuntu8.15
  openssl 0.9.8k-7ubuntu8.15
  ssl-cert 1.0.23ubuntu2
```

Comment: _“Out of the blue”_, _“was working fine until a few days ago”_ – that sounds a lot like the certificate just _expired_ …

Comment: Is there any way to check the expiration? As I say, I would have thought that to be the case also, but it's working fine on our development boxes - both with windows curl and linux curl.

Comment: certificate appears to be fine for another 238 days: http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://xmlpi-ea.dhl.com/XMLShippingServlet